# How to create async query to postgress in flask?

Tags: python, postgresql, flash-message

I have the following blocking code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

def find_places():
   query = "Select ... From ... Where ..."
   result = db.session.execute(query)
   return json.dumps([dict(r) for r in result)

@app.route('/')
def videos():
    return find_places()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    app.run()
```

How can I make this code asynchronous?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [aiopg](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg), it's the best (and possibly the only) asynchronous Postgres library for Python.

They also have optional SQLAlchemy integration. I'll just copy from their README:

```
import asyncio
from aiopg.sa import create_engine
import sqlalchemy as sa

metadata = sa.MetaData()

tbl = sa.Table('tbl', metadata,
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('val', sa.String(255)))

async def create_table(engine):
    async with engine.acquire() as conn:
        await conn.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl')
        await conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE tbl (
                                  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
                                  val varchar(255))''')

async def go():
    async with create_engine(user='aiopg',
                             database='aiopg',
                             host='127.0.0.1',
                             password='passwd') as engine:

        async with engine.acquire() as conn:
            await conn.execute(tbl.insert().values(val='abc'))

            async for row in conn.execute(tbl.select()):
                print(row.id, row.val)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(go())
```